# Как сделать, чтобы комментарии не прерывали складывание кода в IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, settings

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли настроить игнорирование комментариев, либо принудительно включить складку методов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если сделать комментарию такой же отступ как и телу, 4 символа, может быть он нормально сложится?

Comment: Язык какой? Можно наваять что-то на https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zokugun.explicit-folding

Comment: Суть в том что коллеги работающие в других IDE по типу ***Storm, ставят комментарии таким образом. И у них все отлично работает. @Kromster

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Язык PHP (или вообще любой)

Comment: Для каких-то языков есть расширения, которые делают умную свертку. Про PHP не знаю. Для произвольного языка подходит плагин выше.